# Javascript: is there a way to reverse a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am working with pdfs in acrobat and want to be able to execute javascript from a button that I place into the document.  I want the button to return the view to focus on the last hyperlink clicked in the document.

For example:
Let's say there is a footnote on a page that has a hyperlink that refers to the referenced exhibit which is further down in the document.  I want there to be a button that referenced exhibit which would reverse the hyperlink in effect and return to to the source (the citation).

I could do this by hyperlinking back from the source but this doesn't work well if there are multiple references to the source.

Is there a way to do this with javascript?  My programming experience is in R, Stata and Java but none of it is strikingly extensive.

Comment: Been [there](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.140.html#1995411)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: I feel like a total noob, but I pasted that into the action for my button and it didn't do anything.  IS there something more I need to do? Sorry to waste your time...

Comment: Is your source hyperlink sending you to a completely separate page or is it scrolling down to a certain portion of the page? Give me the code for you link (<a></a>)

Comment: I don't have any code for that unfortunately.  I just used the acrobat supplied tools to insert links.